# 2D Turn-based FOSS Linux game with online and hotseat multiplayer

Tags: linux, open-source, game

What 2D FOSS, low-resource, native, turn-based Linux games are available which support at least two players, both locally using the same machine (hotseat) and online?

1. Runs on Linux, natively
2. FOSS (Free and open-source)
3. Low hardware requirements
4. a [turn-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turns,_rounds_and_time-keeping_systems_in_games#Turn-based) game (it should be an actual substantial game, rather than a minigame)
5. Multiplayer:
6. Online: Connect via IP or some room listing type of selection
7. Local: [Hotseat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotseat_%28multiplayer_mode%29) mode (playing on the same device)

I am looking for a game that meets all of these requirements. Note that multiplayer is a mechanic, in the extended [MDA framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDA_framework) ([more here too)](http://www.gamasutra.com/php-bin/news_index.php?story=17464). MDA is an alternative categorization for games, which fixes the blurring of genres as the medium evolves.

Games are software, and have been shown to be on-topic [here](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51/would-video-game-related-question-be-ontopic).

Comment: Most games that has server/client kind of thingy will archive all those requirements. Unless you are more specific (FPS, war, strategic?) I doubt you will get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: While there are lots of FOSS games which play over the net, not many play locally too. I've added the not-FPS requirement to limit possibility of a large amount of answers as you've suggested might happen.

Comment: Not FPS is too Broad still.
You need to give a Actual Genre not "All Genre's EXCEPT this one."

Comment: @Oxinabox: Are you sure there really would be "too many possible answers" for {free + Linux + same-screen multiplayer + online multiplayer} (and if necessary: non-FPS) games? --- Personally I don’t know another match besides Hedgewars, but I just tried searching for some others because of this question and wasn’t successful (I only searched for some minutes, though).

Comment: Not certain, but we want good examples for during private beta. This particular set of requirments may have very few solutions, but as far as examples for Game-rec go i think stating a genre is preferable.
This is my opinion. though.
Perhaps a post on  meta is needed

Comment: Batte of Wesnoth can do all this. I'm scrolling through http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/games/ and am seeing multiple games that match. I agree with @Oxinabox there are too many possible answers. More precisely there is not an answer that could fit most and is therefore "correct".

Comment: warmux matches as well.

Comment: I’d like to try to salvage this question. ConfusedStack, would you be fine with limiting the scope somewhat? For example, requiring turn-based games and a FOSS license (your title/tags say FOSS, but in the question it says that free/gratis is okay, too)? I’ll give it a try by editing now, please revert it if you are not fine with it.

Comment: @unor wesnoth and warmux match still. In fact except racing games (or some sidescroller) I don't know what would be excluded by "turn-based". Still to broad.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer: I’d say it should be no problem that Warmux and Wesnoth match here, too (+ possible other games still unmentioned here) -- how much would be "too many"? I think before closing a question as too broad, there should be some kind of source (e.g. a link to a list/comparison in Wikipedia) showing that there really are too much possible matches.

Comment: @unor The problem is that there won't be a comparsion list that contains so different games like Hedgewars and Wesnoth. But we'll see. I say lets reopen it and if there are too many answers (>10 ?) then we close it and can say we tested it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for fixing it. I will try to limit scope more next time. I thought "natively" was implied, but you guys/gals are right - it should be stated. "Hotseat" is also a good addition / suggestion.

Comment: This is still too broad. Now you're asking to list all Multiplayer turn based games. It is a little better, but still too broad. How about you go into "turn based" a bit more. What kind of turn based? A card game? A puzzle game? A board game? Or something more like tanks?

Comment: I added low resource, and 2D. A card game would be fine, as would a game like 2D tanks as those are aesthetics, and not core mechanics. Turn-based is about mechanics. Please read more about MDA at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDA_framework if you are curious.

Comment: @ConfusedStack Looking at this: Chess and Go would match, wouldn't they? Could you define "Minigame" a bit more so we get an idea where the lower boundary on complexity is?

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer Hmm. that is actually a rather interesting one - I'm not sure I've thought of how that would be defined. I just +1'd that. I am actually going to ask in another thread on gamedev@stackexchange for thoughts. I guess loosely in my mind I'd consider a minigame any game that could easily be a self-contained game within another one, a game that shows all the information on the screen, could have been produced in the dawning of gaming, and/or the average (perhaps even non-gamer) can sit down and instantly understand all the game rules without having to "learn" them via play. ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Hedgewars**](http://www.hedgewars.org/) is a gratis FLOSS (License: GPLv2) turn-based "artillery game, featuring fighting Hedgehogs!". It’s similar to games from the proprietary [*Worms*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worms_%28series%29) series.

[image: Hedgewars gameplay screenshot]

It’s [available](http://hedgewars.org/node/3429) for Android, Apple iOS, FreeBSD, GNU/Linux (*), Mac OS X, and Microsoft Windows.

(*) You can install it from the software repositories in ArchLinux, Debian, Fedora, Gentoo, openSUSE, Ubuntu (and maybe more).

There is also a [WebGL version of Hedgewars](http://hedgewars.org/hwjs/hwjs.html) which can be played in the browser (currently only works with Firefox). (I did not try it.)

It supports the following multiplayer modes:

- [Local → Multiplayer](http://www.hedgewars.org/wiki/LocalGame):

  - play on the same screen against each other
  - play on the same screen together against a computer player
- [Network](http://www.hedgewars.org/wiki/Network_Game_Guide) (all players would need to play with the same version):

  - play in a LAN
  - play online on a dedicated server
  - play online on the official server (I guess you need to [register your nick name first](http://www.hedgewars.org/user/register))

Comment: @Mateo: Yes (as I wrote in the first sentence). Your turn: You may move and use a selected weapon. After you used the weapon (or after the time is up if you just moved), your turn ends and the next player’s turn starts. --- Here’s a random [gamplay video on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4izDpVV6qTo) (just jump to, e.g., minutes 2-3 to see a few turns).

Answer (score 9):

**[Battle for Wesnoth](http://wesnoth.org/)** is a turn base strategy game where you have to wait for the other players to do their turn than can do yours. Its Gameplay is based on the more famous "Heroes of Might and Magic".

In this screenshot you see yourself (figures with red) in a complex fight against two opponents (black and green). The black figure above the castle tried to attack your figure inside the castle and lost 3 HP.
[image: scene from game]

The game is quite complex and to play the tutorial game before actual games is highly recommended. (Units gain advantage due to terrain, day/night, leadership, magic, etc.)

You can play this as hot-seat multiplayer game because everybody takes their turns after another anyway.
If you play this via network you also have to wait for the others to make their turn.

It has full game documentation [here](http://wiki.wesnoth.org/Play), but I've never read much of this site, can't tell how it is.

Wesnoth is FOSS software.

**[Liquid war](http://www.ufoot.org/liquidwar/)** is a very special game (not turn based, but matching the other criteria). You control a pointer where your Liquid tries to get to. You should control this via mouse, but can do it with keyboard as well. It supports multiple of each. When the liquids of two players meet they start to consume each other. So, you need to "surround" you opponent while at the same time ensure that no place of "you" is too thin for you opponent to break through.

It supports hot seat and as of version 6 network game.

The core concept is easy, but this game can be **very** challenging.

In this screenshot you see red and purple being at war quite intense while blue tries to reach the action.
[image: screenshot of liquid war]

Comment: +1 for Battle for Wesnoth.  This is a complex game with really great gameplay as well as a very good single player mode.

Answer (score 3):

Back in the days of DOS, [Scorched Earth](http://www.whicken.com/scorch/) was a family favourite. There is a decent write-up of it [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scorched_Earth_%28computer_game%29).

That was then, and this is now, and now there is **[Scorched3D](http://scorched3d.co.uk/)**, an "open-source, multiplayer modernisation of the classic DOS game Scorched Earth, 'The Mother Of All Games', with fully destructible 3D landcapes and stunning visual effects."

Basically, one tank attempts to wipe out another by lobbing artillery at it. It involves:

- calculating trajectory, velocity, etc. (i.e., aim, shoot! Scorched Earth got there *long* before Angry Birds)
- collecting $$$ to purchase different weapons
- messaging between players ("Hasta la vista, baby!", etc.) to taunt opponents
- more fun than it might sound like!

As for OP's specific criteria:

1. Runs on Linux, natively [image: Yes]
2. FOSS (Free and open-source) [image: Yes]
3. Low hardware requirements [image: Note] [looks low to me](http://scorched3d.co.uk/wiki/index.php/Requirements#Minimum_System_Requirements:.2A)
4. a [turn-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turns,_rounds_and_time-keeping_systems_in_games#Turn-based) game  [image: Yes]
5. Multiplayer: [image: Yes]
6. Online: Connect via IP or some room listing type of selection [image: Yes]
7. Local: [Hotseat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotseat_%28multiplayer_mode%29) mode (playing on the same device) [image: Note] appears to be from comments in community forum, but not 100% clear from docs.

There are a [number of reviews on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=scorched3d&sm=3). Here's a [screenshot](http://scorched3d.co.uk/phpBB3/gallery/):

[image: random screenshot]